# Is it possible to calculate 95% confidence limits of a predicted value of a regression equation when we don't have the raw data?

Tags: regression, confidence-interval

Reading a paper, I realized that a polynomial regression equation was published with its associated standard error and sample size. That regression relates enamel thickness ($y$) and enamel formation time ($x$). I only know the regression equation, not the raw data.
This is the regression equation:

$$y=8.7+0.37x-0.00005x^2\\ (R^2=0.97, \text{standard error}= 0.01, n=20)$$

I have my own data from my sample, and I would like to use this regression and know the confidence interval. For example, I have one value ($x=1210 \text{ microns}$), and its formation time following the regression is 383 days.

I read in several places that the raw data are necessary to calculate the confidence interval for a predicted value.
Is there any way to know it when we don't have the raw data? If so, how?

Comment: What does the standard error refer to? Is it the residual standard error? You have three parameter estimates, so you should have three standard errors for those too.

Comment: In fact I don't know if the s.e. refers to the residual s.e. or not. In the publication they don't mention that. I suppose it refers to the regression equation...

Comment: Is there any possibility to establish the interval limits from these data?

Comment: I think you would need the covariance matrix to calculate the SE of the prediction with multiple predictors.

Comment: When you say "confidence limits of a predicted value" are you talking about a CI for the mean prediction, or an interval for a future observation? It might be possible to place a lower bound on it, at least. Is there any additional information about the x-values?

Comment: Thanks everybody. There is no more information about the x-values. When I am talking about CI for a mean prediction I mean the lower and upper bound of the CI at that x-value (in the example, x=1210)